# Maintain horizontal scroll position page to page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a horizontal scrolling `div` as a menu on my website.

My issue is, when one menu item is clicked and the user gets to the next page that includes the menu, it does not remember the horizontal scroll position. It is important that the active menu item is shown without the user having to scroll to find it again.

I want to target the `div` on all pages so it remembers the horizontal scroll position in the menu bar. I have done a lot of JavaScript investigating and haven't found a similar solution. Other forum users point out using cookies is necessary. Maybe I just don't know how to phrase my keywords? Any assistance would be much appreciated!

[image: Horizontal scrolling div]

I found the below code and I am not taking credit for writing this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var sep = '\uE000'; // an unusual char: unicode 'Private Use, First'

  window.addEventListener('pagehide', function(e) {
    window.name += sep + window.pageXOffset + sep + window.pageYOffset;
  });

  if (window.name && window.name.indexOf(sep) > -1) {
    var parts = window.name.split(sep);
    if (parts.length >= 3) {
      window.name = parts[0];
      window.scrollTo(parseFloat(parts[parts.length - 2]), parseFloat(parts[parts.length - 1]));
    }
  }
});
```

It remembers the vertical page position from page to page. I would, however, like to target a specific div or element to remember the horizontal scroll.

Comment: May be Web Storage API would be better than cookies?

Comment: Could you provide the code you have already tried?

Comment: @LiamStrilchuk I uploaded the code. Hope you can help!

Comment: You know what item is active currently. Simply scroll this element to view instead of *remembering* scroll position

Comment: @Justinas that is actually a very good solution. Thanks for the feedback.